# Is it possible to watch for questions that match two tags?

Tags: support, tag-watching

It is possible to watch a tag, but there are a lot of false positives. Is it possible to watch two tags, such as "regex" and "java", which would return the intersection of those result sets?

Comment: You will have to [wait a little while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/388562)

Comment: Can this be added here? When I hover over the individual tags I can save the query .... but not for both...https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1.9+bug

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1.9+bug/prefs?action=favorite&fkey=xxxxxxxxx does nothing

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can perform this search [`[regex] [java]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex+java?sort=newest) to get a list of questions with the two tags.

From there, you can also get an RSS feed on the bottom of the right sidebar: "[newest regex java questions feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=regex%20java&sort=newest)".

---

If you need some help building advanced search queries, I recommend using my [Advanced Search Helper, Saved Search (Bookmarks), and Navigation Improvements](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011) userscript.

[image]

Features:

1. Search main/meta switcher
2. Switch to main/meta from left sidebar
3. Order-by selector
4. Username & Tag autocomplete
5. **Saved searches**!!!

   - Toggle from search results page

     [image: screenshot]
   - View list via toggle button in Advanced Search Helper

     [image: screenshot]