# Is there a feed of all watched tags somewhere?

Tags: support

I've seen this answer: [Is it possible to watch for questions that match two tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371316/is-it-possible-to-watch-for-questions-that-match-two-tags)

and this: https://stackapps.com/questions/7971/advanced-search-helper-saved-search-bookmarks-and-navigation-improvements (which requires downloading stuff)

But, I'm looking for something built-in to the site ---
I'd like be be able to see the 'tag' view but for my watched tags, instead of just one tag. Is this available somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: It shows you have 18.4k rep yet you are a new contributor to the site?  Why???

Comment: I just realized this is in regards to the meta site - we should really change this to only base it on the main sites not meta.  If you have 18.4k rep on stackoverflow you should not be considered a new contributor on meta.stackoverflow.  That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Discussion here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372906/new-contributor-should-reflect-main-sites-not-meta-sites

Answer (score 19):

That's under development.

You can opt-in to the alpha. See [this post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313940/369403) for more information.

Without using that, you can just use the search to look for multiple tags. If you only search for tags, the result will auto-update.