# Is there a special tag search to show all my watched tags?

Tags: support, tag-watching

Is it possible to use one single dummy / fake / special tag which will show all contents related to my watched tags?

I already searched for special tags, like `[Watched Tags]` but there is nothing like this.
I thought that when I put in a search string `[Watched Tags]` then I see results for all tags which I have set as “Watched”.

I already read [Is there a feed of all watched tags somewhere?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372799) and [Is it possible to watch for questions that match two tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371316).

I also find a way which I describe here: [What do "watched tags" and "ignored tags" do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-watched-tags-and-ignored-tags-do/359490#359490).

Comment: `intags:mine` returns only posts that appear in tags you have marked as favorite. (If you don't have any tags, this operator does nothing. For better results, update your preferences.) -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: The answer that you linked to appears to be deleted. I’m not sure what you attempt to “describe” in that answer, but it’s not advisable to answer FAQ posts with small pieces of knowledge that don’t fully answer the question.

Comment: I’ve also [added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/19177/12) it to the FAQ.